# What is a suspensible component in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm reading this article: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#using-with-suspense

It's referring a concept called "**suspensible**" component.

I have researched, but I can't find any information about what is a so called "**suspensible**" component.

Can anyone explain what it is? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Suspensible"* means replaceable by fallback content while parent `<Suspense>` resolves `async` child components found in its `<template #default>`.

The concept is borrowed from React's [Suspense API](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#suspense).

---

In more detail, `<Suspense>` is a built-in Vue 3 component which renders a `<template #fallback>` instead of the `<template #default>`, until all `async` child components in default template are resolved.

In order to be **suspensible**, a component's rendering needs to depend on a promise:

- be loaded using `() => import('some/path')`
- or use an `async/await` (or any other form of Promise syntax) in its `setup` function

A suspensible component is **suspensed** when included in a `<Suspense>`'s default template, while its parent `<Suspense>` has not resolved all its suspensible components, even if the suspensed component itself has already resolved.

Obviously, `<Suspense>` components themselves are suspensible and suspensing can be nested.

---

Here's a [more detailed explanation](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/) on `<Suspense>` in Vue 3.

---

Among other usages, `<Suspence>` provides an elegant and intuitive way to resolve the common problem of having to wrap child components and templates in `v-if` guarding against non-existent properties on data which has not yet been loaded.

A typical Vue 2 example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('render-items', {
  props: ['items'],
  template: `<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
    <td v-text="item.id"></td>
    <td v-text="item.userId"></td>
    <td v-text="item.title"></td>
  </tr>
</table>`  
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: []
  }),
  computed: {
    hasData() {
      return this.items.length;
    }
  },  
  async created() {
    const items = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(r => r.json());
    this.items = items;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <render-items :items="items" v-if="hasData"></render-items>
  <template v-else>loading...</template>
</div>
```

Same example (more or less) in Vue 3, using `<Suspense>` and `async setup`:

```js
const RenderItems = Vue.defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const items = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(r => r.json());
    return Vue.reactive({ items });
  },
  template: `<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
    <td v-text="item.id"></td>
    <td v-text="item.userId"></td>
    <td v-text="item.title"></td>
  </tr>
</table>`
});
const App = { components: { RenderItems }};
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <render-items></render-items>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      loading...
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</div>
```

One major advantage is in the Vue 3 example we can contain the data fetcher (and the data) in the child component. This is not possible in Vue 2, because:

- the sub-component is only created after data has loaded
- the parent needs to know when the condition changed (so it needs access to the actual condition) in order to switch between rendering fallback content or the child component.

The simplest way to do it in Vue 2 is actually to load the data in parent and pass the result to the child component, via props. If you have a lot of sub-components, this pattern can get messy.

In Vue 3, the responsibility for loading the data and checking the condition can rest entirely with the child-component. Parent doesn't need access to the actual condition.

Just like `<template>`, `<Suspense>` does not create a DOM element.

In the above Vue 3 example, `<RenderItems />` is suspensible.

Answer (score 1):

A suspensible component would be one that is capable of using the new  item in Vue 3.  A suspense item it something that loads and may take a longer time to load, like an API call.  Generally you would be using async/await inside of items that are inside of the suspense item.

A lot of good info here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components

You would use a suspense item to say while items inside of the suspense item are being awaited show something else (like a skeleton loader).